# Как реализовать карусель с горизонтальной полосой прокрутки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, карусель

[image: карусель]
Как реализовать такую карусель, какой плагин делает именно с  горизонтальным скролом, а не кнопками и как стилизовать саму полосу?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример карусели с горизонтальной полосой прокрутки

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!